# How to implement Firebase Messaging flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've updated firebase messaging to the latest and right now I can't get the hand on how to implement the new modifications.

This far I've used:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
});
```

And

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/message',
      arguments: MessageArguments(message, true));
});
```

And this is my original code

```
    class PushNotificationService{
  final FirebaseMessaging fcm = FirebaseMessaging();

  Future initialize(context) async {

    if(Platform.isIOS){
      fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
    }

    fcm.configure(

      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

        fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);

      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

        fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);

      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

        fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);
      },

    );

  }
```

Cant seem to find a way to implement it.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

- change the body of your `initialize` method to include the `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage` and `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp` listeners
- get the initial message using `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()` and run the `onLaunch` callback if the message is not null (i.e the app was launch from a notification while terminated)

```dart
    Future initialize(context) async {
    
       if(Platform.isIOS){
         fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
       }

       //onMessage
       FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
         fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);
       });

       //onResume
       FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
         fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);
       });

       //onLaunch
       final Remote initialMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
       if (initialMessage != null) {
         fetchRideInfo(getRideID(initialMessage), context);
       }
      
    }
```